# Unable to set status bar background color and text color when using MFMailComposeViewController and UIActivityViewController in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistatusbar

In my current application I'm using a green color for my navigation bar and a darker green for the status bar with white text. But currently it is showing the same color for both navigation bar and status bar with white text which is still ok but the problem is that whenever I use UIActivityViewController or MFMailComposeViewController in my apps the status bar background color and text color is different from what I've set for the app theme in AppDelegate.I'm even unable to change them within the controllers. I've faced this problem several times in my Xamarin.iOS apps but did not find any proper way to do this. I've checked so many other threads on this issue but of no use.

Comment: I have set this in ios can i Give that code?

Comment: need to ios code for that ?

Comment: Can you provide the code for what you have tried already?

Comment: Try this key/value in your Info.plist fro the project: `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/>` ?